# Not able to run React-Native app through Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

`C:\Projects\albums>npx react-native run-android`

`info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.`

```
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed setting boot class path.
```

```
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

    at makeError (C:\Projects\albums\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Projects\albums\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Projects\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Projects\albums\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

This is what the error I'm getting while running my app.
Can you please help me with it.

Comment: Can you launch emulator form android studio?

Comment: I have tried, but then also its not working

Comment: be sure to follow all steps in RN docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: I have followed every step provided in the documentation.

Comment: can launch on physical device?

Comment: I have done everything possible.